# jQuery basic help calling a dialog when a give class is listed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this situation:
I have a page where I can edit users info(name, email, phone, etc...). when I click on the edit button, it calls a dialog (modal window), that loads the user data that is already set in the database.
When the user click on the Update button, I do a verification in my controller to make sure he inserted a valid e-mail. If the e-mail is not valid, I have an error and I add a class named "error" into the html label, in this specific dialog. What I'm trying to do is, if there's a mistake, I want the dialog to open right after the verification. As I have this specific class error set only when and where there's a mistake, so I want your help to find a way to call the dialog `$('#addEditUserDialog').dialog('open');` when this condition : `$("#addEditUserDialog label.error")` happens.

I tried doing:

```
if ($("#addEditUserDialog label.error")) {
        $('#addEditUserDialog').dialog('open');
    }
```

but it's calling the dialog even if the class error isnot set.
I know it's a basic question, but I have not much experience with javascript and I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery object is always truthy (that is, it evaluates to true). To test for an element's existence, one needs to use `$().length` (which should be 0 if there are no elements, and will then be false).

```
if ( $("#addEditUserDialog label.error").length ) {
    $('#addEditUserDialog').dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: @Periback Can you accept the correct answer? It adds reputation to the acceptor and the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

try -

```
var className = $("#addEditUserDialog").attr("class");
if (className == "error")
{
    $('#addEditUserDialog').dialog('open');
}
else
{
    alert("Class not found");
}
```

or

```
if ($("#addEditUserDialog").hasClass("error"))
{
    $('#addEditUserDialog').dialog('open');
}
else
{
    alert("Class not found");
}
```